# Integer square root in java

Tags: java, for-loop, integer, root

I am writing a program to get the integer square root of a number.
My Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class IntRoot{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    int num;
    System.out.print("Enter a non-negative integer: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    num = sc.nextInt();
    int i;
    int y=1;
    for (i=1; num>=i+(i+2); i +=2){
        ++y;
    }
    System.out.print(y);
    }
}
```

The program should add odd positive integers one at a time (1+3+5+7+...) until the next sum is less than or equal to num, then count the number of odd numbers used to give the integer square root (and print that number).

eg. integer square root of 12 would be 3, since 1+3+5 = 9, and there are 3 odd numbers in the sum

Currently my program doesn't print the correct number. "i" should start at 1 and increase by 2 each time. This for loop would repeat until the next sum of "i"'s would be greater than "num", and "y" would grow by 1 each time to give the number of times "i" has grown. So if input is 7, "i" should stop when y=2, similarly, if input is 4, i should stop when y=2, and if input is 49, i should stop when y=7.

Is there something wrong with my code? or my logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a few things wrong but here's something that works

```
int currSum = 0;
int oddCount = 0;
for(int i = 1; currSum + i <= num; i+=2) {
   currSum += i;
   oddCount++;
}
```

Basically this does the check that `currSum = 1+3+5....+i < num` and if your current sum is not greater than num, then you are adding the next odd integer to your current sum, incrementing number of odd numbers seen, and checking again.

Comment: really like this solution - its quite simple and doesn't need anything more than necessary. Thanks!

p.s. i think you meant to type "currSum + i <= num - 2" (otherwise the loop would continue when i=num and go over by 1!)

Comment: Hmm, I think the condition is correct, my local tests were good. Is there a value that does not work? I'm trying to find a bad value but to no avail

Comment: when i typed 49 in, i got 8

Comment: Ah yes, you're correct. Locally I had `oddCount = 0` but my answer had `oddCount = 1`. I have updated.

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr - skip to the bottom. Use a do/while loop.

---

How do we get to using a do/while loop? I suggest splitting the "break" condition from your loop. Right now it's more complicated to understand what is happening (which is probably why you are confused).

Something like:

```
int curSum = 0;
for (i=1; i<num; i +=2){
    if (curSum + i >= num) {
        break;
    }
    ++y;
    curSum +=i; 
}
```

Is much more clear. It's easier to read and understand what is actually happening in your loop logic.

You can read through the for loop and nearly exactly, in English, read

- "iterate i, by multiples of 2 (starting at 1, so all odd numbers). Count the number of times you can sum these  until the current sum plus the next value is greater than the input number."

Along this line, I would suggest a bit better variable names:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class IntRoot{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int num;
        System.out.print("Enter a non-negative integer: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        num = sc.nextInt();
        int i;
        int iterations=1;
        int curSum = 0;
        for (i=1; i<num; i +=2){
            if (curSum + i >= num) {
                break;
            }
            iterations++;
            curSum +=i; 
        }

        System.out.print(iterations);
    }
}
```

Last, the question is... given your conditions, are you really "iterate over every number up to your input number?" to which the answer is, "no, you want to iterate *until* a condition is met."

There are better loop structures for this,  such as a [do-while](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) loop:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class IntRoot{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int num;
        System.out.print("Enter a non-negative integer: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        num = sc.nextInt();
        int i=1;
        int iterations=1;
        int curSum = 0;
        do {
            i+=2;
            iterations++;
            curSum +=i; 
        } while (curSum + i < num);

        System.out.print(iterations);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop is just counting:

```
for (i=1; num>=i+(i+2); i +=2){
    …
}
```

Iterates with i having the values of 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, …

If you want to have the values 1, 1+3, 1+3+5, 1+3+5+7, … in your loop you have to do something like this:

```
sum = 1;
for (i = 1; num >= sum; i += 2) {
    sum += i;
    …
}
```

Comment: how do I add a sum of the i's in the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work:

```
int value = 4;
int count = 0;
int i = 0;
for (; count < value; i++) {
    count += i * 2 + 1; // i*2+1 == 1, 3, 5, 7, ...
}

if (count != value) i--;
System.out.printf("The Square Root of %d is %d.\n", value, i);
```

Substitute any value in for `value`. It does exactly what you're trying to do.

EDIT: Sorry, wrote the code in C++. Fixed for Java.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this easier with a `while` loop that you `break` out of. I won't say you can't make it work with a `for` but I think the condition to quit is inside the loop, for cleaner code:

```
while(true)
{
  i += 2;
  s += i;
  if(s + i > num)
     break;
  ++y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the default value of y to 0, as on my test it was allways giving one more.

```
int num;
System.out.print("Enter a non-negative integer: ");
num = 12;
int i;
int y=0;
for (i=1; num>=i+(i+2); i +=2){

System.out.print("Iteration " +i+"|");
    ++y;
}
System.out.print(y);
}
```

I added a couple of s.out.

the out was this. so seem the y=0 gave the valid value.

> Enter a non-negative integer: Iteration 1|Iteration 3|Iteration 5|3

Answer (score 0):

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the value :");
        int num=sc.nextInt();

        int a =num/10;//32
        num=num%10;//1
        int b=a/10;//3
        int c=a%10;
        int total=c+b+num;
        System.out.println("The sum of digit is:" +total);


    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you mind to explain and comment your answer a little further? This will help to understand your approach and make it probably easier for future problems.

Comment: check this [link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/117039/computing-integer-square-roots-in-java-follow-up) for integer square root using java this will help you.